# Simplest way to determinize a C program

Tags: c, standards

Consider the C program below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f() {
  printf("f");
  return 1;
}

int g() {
  printf("g");
  return 2;
}

int main() {
  return f() + g();
}
```

According to the C standard, this program does not have a single deterministic behavior, due to the sum in the `main` function, which consists in two subexpressions, and the following excerpt from the C99 standard:

> §6.5 (...) the order of evaluation of subexpressions and the order in
>   which side effects take place are both unspecified.

Therefore, printing `fg` and `gf` are both valid outputs for this program. In practice, a given compiler will choose a single fixed evaluation order (e.g., left-to-right for gcc in this case), but if I want to reliably compare the output among different compilers, I need to ensure my program has a single defined behavior.

My question is: what is the simplest way to do it? Is there a way to avoid including temporary variables (e.g., `int tmp = f(); return tmp + g();`)?

Comment: This is a pretty academic exercise. In practice, you wouldn't sum (or multiply, subtract, whatever) the results of functions that perform output like this.

Comment: Also, it's not true that a compiler will have a fixed evaluation order. If a compiler can optimize by reordering operations, it will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enforce an evaluation order you need to have a sequence point between the function calls.

The easiest way is to use a local variable to store the intermediate result.

This will rarely be a problem unless you have deep recursion or extremely tough memory constraints.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is direct and simple: avoid unspecified behavior.

For your example case,if the return value of `main` doesn't matter, you can use this:

```
return f(), g();
```

The comma operator can make sure the operands executes left to right.

If you need the value of `f() + g()`, then using a temporary variable is necessary.

Comment: @MitchWheat: no, but then the OP's requirement is quite far-fetched. In practice, you'd either do this, or use a temporary variable to linearize the operations.

Comment: I don't see undefined behavior here.  UB implies [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) are possible.  Which is ***not*** the case here.   In this program, output may correctly be one of two possible outputs, but never nasal demons.

Comment: @abelenky So ,"unspecified behavior" is the right word, right?

Comment: Yes, it looks like Wiki's description of [Unspecified Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unspecified_behavior) fits much better than Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Not from the Standard; the simplest way is using the temporary variable.